# android, eclipse: cant install app when target SDK higher than device's API version

Tags: android, target

My app's target sdk version is 14.
Min sdk version is 8.
Device runs under android 2.2 (API 8).
If I try to install my app on the device via eclipse, android device chooser tells me, I cant install on the device.
However, if I install via command prompt:

```
adb install "path to apk"
```

it works fine. How can I install app via eclipse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the device chooser displays a red "X" for your device. Am I right? This is not a problem, you can still run the App. This doesn't prevent you from running it.

Comment: Ah, it really works)) So funny.. looking at red "X" never had an idea to press OK button, lol.